# Carrying frozen raw meat in checked in baggage

Tags: luggage

I traveled with Oman air from GOA to Muscat on 20/1/2019.
I had raw meat with me, frozen and packed in a cool box in my checked in luggage.

The Oman air staff did not allow me to carry it, hence I removed it and threw it away.

What are the rules about this? Where can I find these on the Oman air website?

Comment: We're not associated with any airline, so we can't put anything on their websites.

Comment: As an example (of another airline), United Airlines' Rule 23 (Baggage) states that that they can refuse to transport luggage that "cannot be accommodated without harming or annoying Passengers or which poses a risk to other baggage or cargo". They may refuse raw meat and the surrounding box by stating that there is a (contamination) risk to the other cargo if the box breaks. Also, delays could cause melting.

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't find the exact link. But almost all countries prohibit to bring non packaged raw meat (Canned items are usually exempted).

It was better that your goods is just confiscated. Usually it comes with a fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "packaged". Unless things have changed since 2005, non-Muslims are allowed to bring small quantities of pork into Oman for personal consumption. I took some sausages in my hold luggage without problems. My bag was searched by Omani Customs, but they were only interested in checking my CDs to ensure that they weren't pornographic DVDs.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that was refused by the airline on departure, not by the customs on arrival. This answer does not touch this point, which may be valid even for domestic flights with no customs present.

Comment: I agree with @VladimirF's comment. This answer isn't addressing the question. The question wants to know why the *airline* confiscated the item. If this answer for example (a) provided a justification for the airline enforcing rules *on behalf* of customs in order to explain the confiscation; or (b) provided an explanation for it being against the airline's terms and conditions, then it would be fine. The answer adds further confusion when talking about fines. A fine for confiscating an item could be imposed by customs, but not by the airline check-in staff.

Comment: I'm not sure if "Usually it comes with a fine" is true. If you enter the UK or US with items that are prohibited for import (but otherwise legal, so things like food, rather than narcotics), _and declare them_, they just confiscate them. You'd only get fined if you didn't declare them and they were found in an inspection. Of course, it might be that these two countries are unusual.